# How can i get the object enhanced by cglib

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, cglib

I'm using spring and cglib and i have those classes:

```
public class A {
   .
   .
   private Souscripteur souscripteur;

   private List<B> contrat;

   // getter and setter
}

public class B {
   .
   .
   private Souscripteur souscripteur;

//getter and setter
}
```

and the Class A and B have the same souscripteur, so when i load the Class A and try to load the class B, i get the Souscripteur of the class B EnhancerByCGLIB.

For that, when i try to do this :

```
if(b.getSouscriteur() instanceof PersonnePhysique) {
//do something
} else {
//do nothing
}
```

when i inspect the code, the object enhanced is a PersonnePhysique, but if(b.getSouscriteur() instanceof PersonnePhysique) return false

My class PersonnePhysique is like this :

```
public class PersonnePhysique extends Souscriteur {
//
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you instantiating personnephysique objects (it appears that you are are not)? Why do you expect different behavior?

Comment: the object enhanced is PersonnePhysique, but if(b.getSouscriteur() instanceof PersonnePhysique) return false

Comment: watch out for the typos: `Souscri[p]teur`...

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate generates proxies based on the declared, expected type (`Souscripteur`), so you'll get a lazy-loaded proxy extending `Souscripteur` - hence, no `PersonnePhysique` in the `instanceof` sense.

You have to avoid testing concrete types here, and rather call polymorphic methods on your entities (which is, by the way, more object-oriented).

Your use case, provided you are calling a method `doSomething()`, would become:

```
b.getSouscriteur().doSomething()
```

with the following implementations:

```
public class Souscripteur {
    public void doSomething() {
        // do nothing
    }
}

public class PersonnePhysique extends Souscripteur {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // do something here
    }
}
```